# Mongoose promise built in but not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Or quite possibly I am doing it wrong, in fact, more than likely I am doing it wrong.

Have a table which contains a "tree" of skill, starting at the root level and may be as deep as ten levels (only two so far), but I want to return it as one big fat JSON structure, so I want to ask the database for each set of data, build my structure then ask for the next level.

Of course if I just send of my requests using mongoose, they will come back at any time, as they are all nice asyncronous calls. Normally a good things.

Looking at the documentation for Mongoose(using 4.1.1) it seems like it has a promise built in, but whenever I try to use it the api call throws a hissy fit and I get a 500 back.

Here is my simple function:

```
exports.getSkills = function(req,res) {
    console.log("Will return tree of all skills");
    for (var i = 0; i<10; i++){
        var returnData = [];
        console.log("Lets get level " + i );
        var query = Skill.find({level: i });//The query function
        var promise = query.exec; //The promise?
        promise.then(function(doc) { //Totally blows up at this point
            console.log("Something came back")
            return "OK";
        });
    }
}
```

The Mongoose documentation on the subject can be found here 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise

Comment: +1 for use of *"Hissy fit"* in a question. But seriously this does seem researched. **But** You also realize you have an synchronous construct ( for loop ) interacting with asynchronous responses (your promises), which will of course not "play well together". This is what I think you **really** need to resolve here, since "blow up" is indeed the apt phrase when you try to do something like this.

Comment: My plan was to use the promise to get moongose to play as synchronous. I.E. I want it to fire of a requests for a level, wait for response then process the next one. Promise might be the wrong way, but I can't figure out the right way:) Come to think of it, I have found that it is quite often I need a design pattern for this, and haven't really found a smooth solution (desperately want to avoid ending up with pyramid of doom).

Comment: Umpph! Which part of the "callback"  argument to `.then()` are you not understanding then?

Comment: I do understand it is a callback, and I am more than happy to set it up so that it calls it ten times, then I'll get the code to check that all ten calls returned successfully before I start sorting the data. My problem is that the code blows up even if I do a single loop (I.E. no loop at all, (var i=0, i<1, i++)), so it seems like using the callback .then() causes the issue.

Comment: Acually this is **exactly** what I have already told you. You say you "understand" but you clearly do not with such an obvious error.

Comment: So if it is so obvious, what is it I am missing. Why does the api call return 500 without executing the code within the callback. (already removed the loop completely, so a single request now to make it simple)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86630/discussion-between-vrghost-and-blakes-seven).

Answer (score 1):

```
var promise = query.exec;
// =>
var promise = query.exec()
```

---

```
exports.getSkills = function(req,res) {
    console.log("Will return tree of all skills");
    var p;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        if (i == 0 ) { 
            p = Skill.find({level:i}).exec();
        } else {
            p.then(function (){
                return Skill.find({level:i}).exec()
            })
        }   
        p.then(function (data) {
            //deal with your data
        })
    }
    p.then(function () {
        // deal with response
    })
}
```